# use javascript code on UIWebView that went to other page (about:blank)

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, gigya

I have an UIWebView, that used to login with External Library (Gigya).
The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
        window.onload = function () {

            gigya.accounts.showScreenSet({
                                         screenSet: 'Login-web',
                                         mobileScreenSet: 'testMobile',
                                         deviceType: 'auto'

                                         });
        }


    **function DisplayEventMessage(eventObj) {
        alert(eventObj.eventName + " event happened");
        window.location="callmycode:cmd=showAlert&var=myVar";
    }

    gigya.socialize.addEventHandlers({
                                     onLogin:DisplayEventMessage,
                                     onConnectionAdded:DisplayEventMessage,
                                     onConnectionRemoved:DisplayEventMessage
                                     }
                                     );**
```

The code asks Gigya SDK to add this page to his delegate; (`gigya.socialize.addEventHandlers`). but when someone logins with Facebook, its opens new tab on normal browser (`about:blank`) but in the `UIWebView`, Its just loading the new site, not a tab. so, the javascript code disabling, because the page is not exists anymore.

how can I still enable  this code even the page not exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just posting the answer if someone will need this help:)

The answer is quite simple, just redirect to the Safari browser.
I can't get it to work with `UIWebView`.
Example code:

```
(Opening safari:)
   -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        (**here the link opening:**)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

(Some code in the site handling the redirect to the application)
(JavaScript)
window.location = "yourapp://<some information needed>";
```

I did it in another way, I recognised the link opening, and started native window from Gigya's SDK to login.